# Bash: mv: target specified is not a directory

Tags: linux, bash, mv

For some reason mv doesn't work properly in my bash script.
This script should rename mp3 files with spaces

```
ls *mp3 > ls2.txt

while read line
do
        sed_name=$(echo $line | sed 's/ /_/g' | sed "s/'//g")
        mv  "'"$line"'" "'"$sed_name"'";
done < ls2.txt

rm ls2.txt
```

but I'm getting the following error mv: target specified is not a directory (mv: указанная цель  не является каталогом)

Comment: This is convoluted, why don't you just do `for i in *.mp3; do...; done`?

Comment: that way looks easier. I'll try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "'"$line"'".. just try

mv "$line" "$sed_name"

Comment: strange I thought I tried that...  but that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also, use double-quotes in the echo command (`echo "$line"`), or it'll have trouble with filenames with more than one space in a row.